# Trying to understand the sigma expansion in an answer

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Iteration 2: Reassign cluster labels according to the smallest squared distances:
$\begin{array}{ccccc}\text { Data point } X_{i} & \left\|X_{i}-(0,1)\right\|^{2} & \left\|X_{i}-(4,4)\right\|^{2} & \left\|X_{i}-(6,1)\right\|^{2} & \text { Cluster Label } \\ (6,-1) & 40 & 29 & 4 & 3 \\ (4,3) & 20 & 1 & 8 & 2 \\ (6,3) & 40 & 5 & 4 & 3 \\ (1,1) & 1 & 18 & 25 & 1 \\ (4,5) & 32 & 1 & 20 & 2 \\ (-1,1) & 1 & 34 & 49 & 1\end{array}$

$$
\begin{aligned}
&\left\{C_{l_{1}}, C_{l_{2}}, C_{l_{3}}\right\}=\{\{(1,1),(-1,1)\},\{(4,3),(4,5)\},\{(6,-1),(6,3)\}\} \\
&\left\{\mu_{l_{1}}, \mu_{l_{2}}, \mu_{l_{3}}\right\}=\{(0,1),(4,4),(6,1)\}
\end{aligned}
$$
The cost function which is the sum of the distances of the data points from each cluster to their centroids is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
C\left(l_{1}, l_{2}, l_{3}, \mu_{l_{1}}, \mu_{l_{2}}, \mu_{l_{3}}\right)=& \frac{1}{6} \sum_{l_{j}=1}^{K=3} \sum_{i=1}^{N=6}\left\|X_{i}-\mu_{l_{j}}\right\|^{2} \\
=& \frac{1}{6}\left\{\left\|X_{1}-\mu_{l_{3}}\right\|^{2}+\left\|X_{2}-\mu_{l_{2}}\right\|^{2}+\left\|X_{3}-\mu_{l_{3}}\right\|^{2}\right.\\
&\left.+\left\|X_{4}-\mu_{l_{1}}\right\|^{2}+\left\|X_{5}-\mu_{l_{2}}\right\|^{2}+\left\|X_{6}-\mu_{l_{1}}\right\|^{2}\right\} \\
=& \frac{1}{6}\{4+1+4+1+1+1\}=\frac{12}{6}=2
\end{aligned}
$$

Hi, I was reading a solution. But I didn't understand how the author find this sigma expansion, that is I didn't understand the following:How did get the author these, can you explain?

$\begin{aligned}=& \frac{1}{6}\left\{\left\|X_{1}-\mu_{l_{3}}\right\|^{2}+\left\|X_{2}-\mu_{l_{2}}\right\|^{2}+\left\|X_{3}-\mu_{l_{3}}\right\|^{2}\right.\\ &\left.+\left\|X_{4}-\mu_{l_{1}}\right\|^{2}+\left\|X_{5}-\mu_{l_{2}}\right\|^{2}+\left\|X_{6}-\mu_{l_{1}}\right\|^{2}\right\} \end{aligned}$

Comment: @callculus42 This is from Machine Learning course. I edited post.

Comment: @callculus42 Did you see?

Comment: Yes, I see. See my anser.

Comment: I don't think that cost function is right, at least for this problem.

Comment: @aschepler Why not?

Comment: @callculus42 Agreeing with your own answer, we want just the minimum difference for each $i$, not all 18 differences. So the $\sum_{l_j=1}^{K=3}$ notation shouldn't be there, and in fact gets ignored on the very next line.

Comment: @aschepler I agree. Maybe you can say, that the distances are set equal to 0, if they the combination is not regarded. But you have to sum the cluster centroids as well, since you have 3 different cluster.

Comment: Looks like instead we use $$C = \frac{1}{6} \sum_{i=1}^6 \min_{l_j=1}^3 ||X_i-\mu_{l_j}||$$

Comment: @aschepler I'm not sure if this notation is right. At this [link](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/k-means-clustering-optimizing-cost-function-mathematically-1ccae156299f) they work with a binary variable.

Comment: @callculus42 That's a useful way of writing the same thing in terms of variables, in order to apply some techniques.

Comment: @aschepler Yes. For me as a former economics student the application of an algorithm/heuristic was more important then the notation.

Answer (score 1):

You have three  cluster centroids $\left\{\mu_{l_{1}}, \mu_{l_{2}}, \mu_{l_{3}}\right\}=\{(0,1),(4,4),(6,1)\}$. Now you (re-)assign 6 points to one of the 3 clusters with the regard of the centroid. You choose the smallest (squared) distance between the point and the three centroids and assign the corresponding point to the corresponding cluster.

[image]

In total you have 6  distances due the 6 points. The other combination/distances are not regarded.

Finally you calculate the arithmetic mean. The squared distance between $X_1$ and the centroid of cluster $3$ is $(6-6)^2+(-1-1)^2=0+4=4$